# Mysql SUM unique if not empty

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
id | c1 | c2
1  | aa | 5
2  |    | 1
3  |    | 3
4  | aa | 5
```

I want to select `SUM(c2)` and if there are duplicated values on `c1` then it will count only one row (duplicated `c1` allways have them same `c2`), But I also want that if `c1` is empty - then count his `c2` anyway.

Output of the example should be: `9` (5+1+3)

Comment: if 5,bb,1 row exists , you want aa, 9 and bb , 1 as output?

Comment: @radar I didn't understand your question. But if there is another row `5 | bb | 1`, Then the output will be `10`, because I want the `SUM` of `c2`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be work (but is a little expensive in query time)

```
select sum(sum(c2),(select sum(c2) from table where c1 is not null)) from table where c1 is null group by c1;
```

Comment: Syntax error. I think you are missing `)` somewhere